# T-Sql: Select Rows where at least two fields matches condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got a table, let's call it `values` with a primary key and five integer fields, like this:

```
id  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
1    4     3     4     5     3
2    2     3     2     2     2
3    5     4     1     3     3
4    1     4     3     4     4
```

Now I need to select all rows where at least any two of the five value fields got the value 4. So the result set should contain the first row (id=1) and the last row (id=4).

I started with a simple OR condition but there are too many combinations. Then I tried a sub-select with HAVING and COUNT but no success.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [**`VALUES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)  to construct an inline table containing your fields. Then query this table to get rows having at least two fields equal to 4:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM (VALUES (val1), (val2), (val3), (val4), (val5)) AS t(v)
  WHERE t.v = 4) AS x
WHERE x.cnt >= 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5219ad/1)

Comment: Great solution as well. I will choose this way because CROSS APPLY is more familiar to me than UNPIVOT. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Although `cross apply` is fast, it might be marginally faster to simply use `case`:

```
select t.*
from t
where ((case when val1 = 4 then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when val2 = 4 then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when val3 = 4 then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when val4 = 4 then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when val5 = 4 then 1 else 0 end)
      ) >= 2;
```

I will also note that `case` is ANSI standard SQL and available in basically every database.

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial to solve if your data is normalized - so lets use `UNPIVOT` to normalize the data and then solve it:

```
declare @t table (id int not null, val1 int not null, val2 int not null,
                  val3 int not null, val4 int not null, val5 int not null)
insert into @t(id,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5) values
(1,4,3,4,5,3),
(2,2,3,2,2,2),
(3,5,4,1,3,3),
(4,1,4,3,4,4)

select
    id
from
    @t t
        unpivot
    (valness for colness in (val1,val2,val3,val4,val5)) r
group by id
having SUM(CASE WHEN valness=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2
```

Results:

```
id
-------
1
4
```

Of course, you can probably come up with better names than `valness` and `colness` that describes *what* these pieces of data (the numbers being stored and the numbers embedded in the column names) actually are.