# SQLalchemy: select rows that satisfy a condition in two or more columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model (with underlying SQLite) similar to this one (stripped-down version of the one I'm using):

```
class Variant(Base):

    __tablename__ = "variants"

    variant_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    freq1 = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    freq2 = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    freq3 = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    freq4 = Column(Float, nullable=False)
```

I need to pick (using the ORM) those `variant_id` which have a frequency greater than 1% (0.01) in *at least two columns*.

So, a hypotethical record like

```
1    0.1   0   0.0025 0.001
```

would not be picked

and one like

```
670   0.5    0.01 0.001 0
```

would instead be picked up.

My trouble is that I can't quite figure out what is the correct way to use the ORM for this.

So far I've "cheated" using `case`, but it looks a bit ugly and not immediately straightforward (inspired by [T-Sql: Select Rows where at least two fields matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011905/t-sql-select-rows-where-at-least-two-fields-matches-condition)):

```
from sqlalchemy import case

condition1 = case([(Variant.freq1 >= 0.01), 1], _else=0)
condition2 = case([(Variant.freq2 >= 0.01), 1], _else=0)
condition3 = case([(Variant.freq3 >= 0.01), 1], _else=0)
condition4 = case([(Variant.freq4 >= 0.01), 1], _else=0)

condition = (condition1 + condition2 + condition3 + condition4) >= 2

result = session.query(Variant).filter(condition).with_entities(Variant.variant_id)
```

However it looks a bit clunky and it basically repeats the same condition over and over. Is there a clearer solution (working with SQLite, which is what I'm using)?

Comment: Your solution is good. If you really have many such columns you could simplify it with list comprehensions.